# How to structure array of items to create an array of objects

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

My server expects an object like the following:

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "detail":[
        {"iddetail":1},
        {"iddetail":2}
    ]
}
```

In the frontend I have a control that takes multiple details:

```
<v-autocomplete
   v-model="items">
</v-autocomplete>
```

As my server expects:

```
 "detail":[
        {"iddetail":1},
        {"iddetail":2}
    ]
```

But my frontend returns:

```
items = [1,2]
```

I do the following:

```
data.items.map(function(x){
   data.detail.push({iddetail:x})
});
```

That works, but the question is whether it can be done in a simpler and more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but maybe this

```
data.detail = items.map((x) => ({iddetail:x}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = [1,2];
const data = {
   name: '...',
   detail: items.map( i => ({iddetail:i}) )
};
```

And of course, it's always more convenient to have similar format between api and front code but small conversion is good enough